# Not able to get text which is not inside any tag Using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How can i get "File transfer overdue for 3PAR/INSERV/CZ3602WT5A" text using selenium webdriver. which is not inside any tag.
Not able to get text for an element using Selenium  How to get text of element that is not inside html tag using Selenium webdriver

```
 <body bgcolor="white">

        <h2>HPE 3PAR StoreServ 8200 2N Fld Int Base - csi - File transfer overdue for 3PAR/INSERV/CZ3602WT5A</h2>
                <p style="text-align:center"><em>Case data updated: 2017-04-05_10.38</em><br /></p>


        <table class="noborder">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="label">
                    Product Number:<br />
                </td>
                <td class="data">
                    <a href="https://myprs.hp.com/myprse/internal/myprsQueryDirect.do?directFlag=true&amp;myprsaction=Submit&amp;products=K2Q36A&amp;country=US&amp;currency=USD&amp;priceListType=&amp;incoTerm=DDP&amp;pricingProc=HPLP01" target="_blank">K2Q36A</a><br />
<!--Product Number: K2Q36A-->
                </td>
                <td class="label">
                    Open Date:<br />
                </td>
                <td class="data">
                    2017-02-26 17:19:56.0<br />
<!--Open Date: 2017-02-26 17:19:56.0-->
                </td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    Serial Number:<br />
                </td>
                <td class="data">
                    CZ3602WT5A<br />
<!--Serial Number: CZ3602WT5A-->
                </td>
                <td class="label">
                    Close Date:<br />
                </td>
                <td class="data">
                    2017-02-27 09:24:04.0<br />
<!--Close Date: 2017-02-27 09:24:04.0-->
                </td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    Product Description:<br />
                </td>
                <td class="data">
                    HPE 3PAR StoreServ 8200 2-node Field Integrated Storage Base<br />
<!--Product Description: HPE 3PAR StoreServ 8200 2-node Field Integrated Storage Base-->
                </td>
                <td class="label">
                    Days Open:<br />
                </td>
                <td class="data">
                    1<br />
<!--Days Open: 1-->
                </td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    Customer:<br />
                </td>
                <td class="data">
                    EUSKO LEGEBILTZARRA PARLAMENTO VASCO<br />

                </td>
                <td class="label">
                    Case Status:<br />
                </td>
                <td class="data">
                    Closed<br />
<!--Case Status: Closed-->
                </td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    Country:<br />
                </td>
                <td class="data">
                    Spain<br />
<!--Country: Spain-->
                </td>
                <td class="label">
                    Any Onsite:<br />
                </td>
                <td class="data">
                     No<br />
<!--Onsite: No-->
                </td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    Warranty Applied:</td>
                <td class="data">05R-Norml Contract</td><td class="label">
<!--Warranty: 05R-Norml Contract-->
                    Multiple Visits:<br />
                </td>
                <td class="data">
                     No
<!--Multiple Visits: No-->
                </td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">Repair Class:</td>
<td class="data">Repair Class NA in SFDC<!--Repair Class: Repair Class NA in SFDC--></td><td class="label">
                    Number of Parts Used:<br />
                </td>
                <td class="data">
                    <!--Parts Used Start-->0<!--Parts Used End--><br />
<!--Number of Parts Used: 0-->
                </td></tr></tbody></table>
<br />
<!--Cut here-->     <table class="log">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>Case Log</td></tr></tbody></table>
<br />
        <table class="noborder">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="casetitle">
HPE 3PAR StoreServ 8200 2N Fld Int Base - csi - File transfer overdue for 3PAR/INSERV/CZ3602WT5A
</td></tr></tbody></table>
<br />
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="issueRecord">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-26 17:19:56.0 -Sunday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 0 / M:0)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Issue</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:carlos.taboada@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">carlos.taboada@hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
File Transfer Overdue issue. Probably customer network or Service Processor Issue<br />
<br />

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="record">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-26 17:19:56.003 -Sunday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 0 / M:0)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Additional Product Info</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:carlos.taboada@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">carlos.taboada@hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
ProductLine - 4A<br />
FirmwareVer - <br />
SoftwareVer - <br />
OperatingSystemVer - <br />
City - VITORIA-GASTEIZ<br />

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="environmentRecord">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-26 17:19:56.003 -Sunday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 0 / M:0)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Environment</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:carlos.taboada@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">carlos.taboada@hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
SW Version4.4.0.GA-30ModelVMware-Virtual-Platform<br />
<br />

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="record">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-26 17:19:56.007 -Sunday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 0 / M:0)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Additional Case Info</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:carlos.taboada@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">carlos.taboada@hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
Origin - STaTS<br />
RecordType - GSD CSC Case Closed<br />
SupportType - Diagnosis (Level 1)<br />
Severity - 3-NORMAL<br />
Language - Spanish<br />
ResolutionType - Remote Resolve<br />
ResolutionCode - Resolved<br />
ResolutionSubCode - HW Issue<br />
NewInstall: No<br />
InstallIssue: <br />
ErrorCode - <br />
Comments - IH 3PAR Aler SIS FOU<br />
ResolutionCategory - <br />
Outage - No<br />

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="resolutionRecord">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-26 17:19:56.007 -Sunday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 0 / M:0)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Resolution</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:carlos.taboada@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">carlos.taboada@hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
Summary:<br />
<br />
<br />
Details:<br />
<br />
They had a blackout. everyhting it is OK. we can close the case.<br />
<br />

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="causesRecord">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-26 17:19:56.007 -Sunday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 0 / M:0)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Causes</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:carlos.taboada@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">carlos.taboada@hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
<br />
FTO<br />
<br />

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="warrantyRecord">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-26 17:19:56.01 -Sunday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 0 / M:0)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Warranty</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:carlos.taboada@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">carlos.taboada@hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
EntitleSummary - HPE Hardware Maintenance Onsite Support  4HR Response / 9X5; Global Coverage<br />
ServicePortfolio - Contract<br />
Response - 4HR<br />
Coverage - 9x5<br />
WarrantyExceptionDetail - <br />
ExceptionReason - <br />
ExceptionProcess -<br />

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="record">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-26 17:19:56.01 -Sunday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 0 / M:0)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">ExternalInfo</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:carlos.taboada@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">carlos.taboada@hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
File transfer overdue for 3PAR/INSERV/CZ3602WT5A<br />

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="record">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-26 17:19:58.0 -Sunday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 0 / M:0)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Chatter</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:cscapiuser@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">cscapiuser@hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
HPE Serial Number: CZ3602WT5A       HPE Product Name: K2Q36A       3PAR Serial Number: CZ3602WT5A   <br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
RAPDB Comments: --------<br />
Analysis<br />
--------<br />
RAP History:<br />
   In the last 30 days, 0 FTO RAPs have been processed<br />
InServ vs SP FTO:<br />
   The call home times are equal<br />
InServ Connection:<br />
   The files times are within 24 hours<br />
SP Config:<br />
   Port 5782 or 5783 is down: mgmt/cli connection is not up<br />
Axeda Ping:<br />
   The last Axeda connection was 1 Days, 7 Hours, 21 Minutes, 21 Seconds ago<br />
Axeda Mute:<br />
   This device is not muted<br />
--------<br />

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="record">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-26 23:29:51.0 -Sunday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 6 / M:9)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Email_text</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:donot_contact_sfdc_automated_case_user@groups.ext.hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">donot_contact_sfdc_automated_case_user@groups.ext.hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
<a href="\\c9w16206.itcs.hpecorp.net\SFDC_CSC_CASELOGS\2017\Feb\27\5002700000qDsziAAC_02s2700000Vt6TwAAJ_email.txt" target="_blank">5002700000qDsziAAC_02s2700000Vt6TwAAJ_email.txt</a>

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="record">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-26 23:31:57.0 -Sunday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 6 / M:12)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Plan of Action</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:ajay.singh3@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">ajay.singh3@hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
Subject - POA<br />
Status - Completed<br />
ActivityText - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br />
<br />
Plan of Action: Communicate below to the customer -<br />
<br />
 <br />
<br />
1.  Please verify if you can reach the SP from your internal network via <a href="http://SPIPDADDRESS" target="_blank">http://SPIPDADDRESS</a> and refer to the below link to verify if the SP is sending files home :<br />
<br />
 <br />
<br />
<a href="http://h20195.www2.hp.com/V2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=4AA5-1582ENW&amp;cc=us&amp;lc=en" target="_blank">http://h20195.www2.hp.com/V2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=4AA5-1582ENW&amp;cc=us&amp;lc=en</a> <br />
<br />
 <br />
<br />
If not, let us know a convenient date and time to setup a VR session and take a look at the SP.<br />
<br />
 <br />
<br />
2.  Patch update needed (P003) – please confirm if we can go ahead and deploy the patch on the SP. It is non-intrusive and can be performed anytime remotely or through HP Virtual Room. Ensure the ‘Serial Cable’ is not connected to the physical SP during the patch installation.<br />
<br />
 <br />
<br />
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br />
<br />
 <br />
<br />
Onsite service required: No. this action can be performed remotely.<br />
<br />
 <br />
<br />
Special Instructions: For any further details on POA, please contact case owner or his team via chat or e-mail ftocore@hp.com. <br />
<br />
 <br />
<br />
After the POA is followed wait for an hour, then please verify the call home using the below steps :<br />
<br />
 <br />
<br />
1. Login to STATs and under Reports tab click on Transfer Status Report<br />
<br />
2. Type/Paste the InServ serial under General keyword search and click Search.<br />
<br />
3. If ‘no data found’ under results, issue is resolved.<br />
<br />
3. If not, please get back to connectivity team for further POA.<br />
<br />
 <br />
<br />
NOTE: Before contacting FTO team in order to troubleshoot, please ensure customer is on the VR ready with putty session and Keyboard converted to English (US).<br />
<br />
How to change Keyboard:<br />
<br />
·         Click Start &gt; type intl.cpl in start search box and press ENTER.<br />
<br />
·         On the Keyboards and Language tab, click Change keyboards &gt; Click ADD<br />
<br />
·         Expand the language 'English (USA)' &gt; Expand Keyboard &gt; Select US-International.<br />
<br />
·         In the Default input language list, click US-international and click OK 2 times.<br />
<br />
 <br />
<br />
**************** End of POA *****************<br />

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="record">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-27 00:05:01.0 -Monday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 6 / M:45)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Chatter</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:fernando.garzon@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">fernando.garzon@hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
[DIAGNOSIS_QUALIFICATION] / [Non-Standard Diagnosis]<br />
3PAR 8000 CSI Service Delivery Instructions Attention! This product is a 2 node system which is eligible for CSI (Customer Self install) and also eligible for remote and onsite installation support via CSC. Please verify with the customer if this is a new system/installation and provide up to 1 hour installation support. Please follow the steps below: 1. Entitle the case on the warranty/SAID/Care Pack of the product 2. Put CSI in the case title 3. Advise the customer that although it is a CSI, CSC is able to offer 1 hour of remote support to help resolve the installation issue. 4. If CSC manage to resolve the issue, close the case as usual. 5. If no resolution is achieved in the 1 hour of remote support, offer to connect the customer with Installation Services to purchase Installation Support. a. If the customer accepts please do the following: For all regions 1. Advise the customer to contact local sales for purchasing I&amp;S Care Pack 2. Submit One Lead - <a href="https://ent301.sharepoint.hp.com/teams/Global-ONELead/SitePages/Default.aspx" target="_blank">https://ent301.sharepoint.hp.com/teams/Global-ONELead/SitePages/Default.aspx</a> and tell the customer to expect a call from the sales team b. If the customer doesn’t accept the offer, entitle the case according the internal gratis process, offer to send a CE Onsite as an exception and dispatch the case to your local country Queue For all regions Location code: 52JGE03700001Y00 Authorizing Employee: Sandra.s@hpe.comless<br />
<br />

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="record">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-27 09:20:01.0 -Monday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 16 / M:0)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Troubleshooting</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:carlos.taboada@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">carlos.taboada@hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
Subject - Troubleshooting<br />
Status - Completed<br />
ActivityText - they had a blackout and the already up the machines. so we can close the case.<br />

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="record">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-27 09:20:52.0 -Monday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 16 / M:0)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Plan of Action</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:carlos.taboada@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">carlos.taboada@hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
Subject - POA<br />
Status - Completed<br />
ActivityText - - close the case. they are agree.<br />

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="record">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-27 09:24:09.0 -Monday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 16 / M:4)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Closing your Case</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:carlos.taboada@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">carlos.taboada@hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
Subject - Closing your Case<br />
Status - Completed<br />
ActivityText - <br />

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Record Header Start-->
        <table class="record">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="rleft">2017-02-27 09:24:10.0 -Monday- <span style="font-weight:normal;"> (Elapsed Time D: 0 / H: 16 / M:4)</span></td>
                <td class="rcenter">Email_text</td>
                <td class="rright">By: <a href="mailto:donot_contact_sfdc_automated_case_user@groups.ext.hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE  %20%0D%0A">donot_contact_sfdc_automated_case_user@groups.ext.hpe.com</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--Record Header End-->
<a href="\\c9w16206.itcs.hpecorp.net\SFDC_CSC_CASELOGS\2017\Feb\27\5002700000qDsziAAC_02s2700000VtM75AAF_email.txt" target="_blank">5002700000qDsziAAC_02s2700000VtM75AAF_email.txt</a>

<br />
<!--End Section-->
<!--Cut here-->
<br />
<br />
                <p style="text-align:center"><em>Email call technicians: <a href="mailto:carlos.taboada@hpe.com;%20cscapiuser@hpe.com;%20donot_contact_sfdc_automated_case_user@groups.ext.hpe.com;%20ajay.singh3@hpe.com;%20fernando.garzon@hpe.com?subject=Question%20on%20Case%20Number:%205317571991&amp;body=Hello,%0D%0A%0D%0ARegarding%20case:%205317571991%0D%0Ahttps://gcsstools-pro-cloud.glb.itcs.hp.com/QVC/Webforms/CaseDetails.aspx?Caseid=5317571991&amp;Company=HPE %20%0D%0A">Click Here</a></em><br /></p>
<!--Tech Emails: carlos.taboada@hpe.com;%20cscapiuser@hpe.com;%20donot_contact_sfdc_automated_case_user@groups.ext.hpe.com;%20ajay.singh3@hpe.com;%20fernando.garzon@hpe.com-->
                <p style="text-align:center"><em>This case file was generated by <a href="https://hpenterprise.sharepoint.com/teams/tce-supportability/TextScanner2DB/Forms/New%20Default.aspx" target="_blank">TextScanner2DB</a> version 2.03</em><br /></p>

 </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your text is in an `<h2>`.

Try (C# code, Java will be similar):

```
string h2text = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > h2")).Text;
```

The value of h2text should end up being:

> "HPE 3PAR StoreServ 8200 2N Fld Int Base - csi - File transfer overdue for 3PAR/INSERV/CZ3602WT5A"

I also see (what you are likely asking about) a `<!-- Record Header -->` with the text in it. It looks like the `<body>` element is the container. That is unfortunate because calling .Text on the body would return all such text. It would be up to you to parse that string.

Comment: I don't want text which is under h2 tag . I want to select "SW Version4.4.0.GA-30ModelVMware-Virtual-Platform" this text which is not under any tag in this html code

Comment: As the later part of my answer points out, that text is in the body tag. So you can extract the text and then parse that string for what you are looking for.